# Analysis of interaction tables

Tags: r, interaction

I have two tables of interactions. One represents the number of times that a clownfish of a given species is found in an anemone of a given species. One represents the number of times that a clownfish of a given species is found in the same anemonae than a clownfish of another species.

```
Table_anemone_fish

      Fish_a    Fish_b   Fish_c
An_A    23        56       12
An_B    12        5        5
An_C    23        10       68
```

Note: Summing this table gives the total number of anemones in my sample.

```
Table_fish_fish

        Fish_a    Fish_b   Fish_c
Fish_a   NA         7        3
Fish_b    7        NA        1
Fish_c    3         1        NA
```

Note: Most of the times the fishes live with no other species and they are therefore not represented in this table. The frequency of each fish species can be obtain with `Table_anemone_fish`

The questions I want to answer are:

- Is there differential preference of fish species in choosing their anemones?
- Is there different preference of fish species in choosing with which other species to live with?

To answer this post one can simply gives the kind of test to use and their philosophy or even better, one might give an example of how to analyze these data with R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a chi-square test for both ... although with the low sample sizes in the second example, you may want to use Fisher's exact test instead.

The Quick-R website gives some examples of how to code these analyses in R, http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html